# Difference between "life itself" and "life it's self"

Tags: meaning

I read these sentences in the Google Books.

( life it's self )

1. I love you more than life it's self.
2. My love is greater than life it's self.

( life itself )

1. Your love is better than life itself.
2. I loved her more than life itself.

What's the difference "life it's self" and "life itself"?

Comment: Please add links to your findings of  "life it's self."

Comment: ["I love you more then life it's self"](https://books.google.com/books?id=sTqNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22I+love+you+more+then+life+it%27s+self%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijhb34re7dAhUEJ1AKHVy3Aw8Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) is obviously a mistake - you have *then* instead of *than* and *life it's self* instead of *life itself*.

Comment: The possessive of "it" is "its" (or reflexive "itself").  "It's" is always a contraction of "it is".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Life it's self* is a mistake.

First of all, the contraction *it's* means *it is*. (The possessive of *it* is *its*, without the apostrophe.)

So, to say *life it's self* is the same as saying *life it is self*.

If you added a comma to that, the sentence might make some kind of strange philosophical sense:

> Life, it is self.

But if you append that to the first part of one of your sentences, it become even more strange—and almost impossible to interpret in any way:

> I love you more than life, it is self.

---

On the other hand, the use of the self-reflective pronoun in a sentence makes perfect sense:

> I love you more than life itself.

---

The simple answer is that *life it's self* is a mistake.

Even if you want to argue that it's been used deliberately, it has a totally different meaning than *life itself*. (And, based on the particular sentence into which it's inserted, I couldn't tell you what that meaning is.)